# Stack Snippets syntax completely borks when indented by four spaces

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, code-formatting

Here's a Stack Snippet:

```js
for(var o of document.getElementsByTagName("input")){(o=>o.addEventListener("change",e=>console.log(o.value=o.value?o.value[0]:"")))(o)};
```

```css
input{width:1em;}
```

```html
<input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input />
```

Here's the markup to create such a Stack Snippet:

```
    for(var o of document.getElementsByTagName("input")){(o=>o.addEventListener("change",e=>console.log(o.value=o.value?o.value[0]:"")))(o)};
    input{width:1em;}
    <input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input /><input />
```

Oh. In the edit window it looks like this:

```
<pre>fed8cd34-c447-9c25-6a88-70385d84a60e</pre>
```

(except with a UUID that changes randomly whenever I type a key into the edit window) but in the actual question, it looks much more hideous, as you can see.

Comment: and why you want to indent a snippet?

Comment: You may want to be explicit about what you expected to see instead. I would expect to see all of the indented section to be treated as a code block, including the HTML comments that make up the snippet syntax, certainly.

Comment: @TemaniAfif how else could you talk about that syntax as code? This is a real bug, the markup should not be treated as a snippet inside a code block, whatever the use cases might be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters a snippet is a code, so we know it's a code, why indenting it as a code?

Comment: @TemaniAfif try posting an answer on Meta demonstrating what that syntax to mark up a snippet looks like. You can’t, because you can’t put the syntax in a code block.

Comment: @TemaniAfif We *can* put Markdown and HTML in a code block, so we can normally “escape” such syntax and show it inraw form. That we can’t with the snippet markup is a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would also expect to see all of the indented section treated as a code block.